# Why my apk file can't install after android update?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, mobile, build.gradle, apk

Good day. I made a game for mobile phones. I created the game in Unity 2018. I build an Apk file, which is used to install the game on the device. The game is on the Android platform. I put my Apk file in my Xiaomi phone and everything works as it should. The game installs normally and can then be played normally. I also put the game on a Samsung phone, where everything also worked as it should. But after the last android update, I got a problem. After the update, my game was uninstalled and when I want to install it again, I click on the Apk file, and it says this error: *"An error occurred while parsing the package"*. I thought it was because I don't have the correct target version of Android set in unity, but this is probably not it. I set the target to the highest possible and also installed the latest SDK files using Android Studio. does anybody know what the problem is and why I can't install my game on Samsung phones?

[image]

Comment: not sure but is "Allow installation from unknown resources" enabled?

Comment: You might try using adb to install the apk. When it fails it may give you a more helpful and specific error message.

Comment: Make sure your APK is signed with apksigner (V2 signing scheme). This is a requirement since Android 12. Also there were some new requirements in what must be declared in the manifest. Google Play Console warns you about these things if you publish there.

Comment: Try changing install location from "prefer external" to "automatic". That might fix the problem